# Adobe Illustrator CS6 on Mojave with Java 8?

Tags: java, adobe

I ran into the common issue where Illustrator CS6 was unable to open in newer Mac OS version and asking for Java 6 to be installed.

While I have already installed Java 8, I found this thread where a few answers pointed to the possibility of using Java 8 as long as two empty directories are created: [Adobe Illustrator CS6 with Java 8?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180899/adobe-illustrator-cs6-with-java-8/)

However, it appears that most users there are using El Capitan or older versions, and since there are some SIP related operation involved, to be on the cautious side, I want to know if anyone tried/knew the same solution proposed in the above thread would work for Mojave (10.14.6)? Would this cause any issue with future updates?

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by Zac Jackson still applies to Mojave: you would have to disable SIP in order to create the required folders. Illustrator's reliance on Java is very slight: the main problem is the 'check' at startup.

Arguably, it's easier just to install Java 6 SE anyway. Java 6 doesn't interfere with Java 8, you can have both installed with no problem.

Only Illustrator and Dreamweaver need Java: the other CS6 apps do not.

However, as Mojave gets older and older, your best option is to run Creative Suite inside a virtual machine running an older OS, like El Cap, and/or migrate to cheaper, more up-to-date apps, like Affinity Designer, that are just as good, if not better, for many uses.